# Refactoring angular resource chaining

Tags: angularjs

Basically i have a angular resource API service as follow. I have use the nested chaining method as below which i think is not so good in coding perspective (especially when there are multiple chaining needed)

```
angular.module('user')
.factory('UserAPI', ['$resource'],
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('User', {},
        {
            GetUserDetail1: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url1
            },
            GetUserDetail2: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url2
            }
        }
    }
)

UserAPI.GetUserDetail1({ ID: id }).$promise.then(function (res) {
    UserAPI.GetUserDetail2({ ID: res.userID }).$promise.then(function (res1) {

    }, function (errRes1) {

    });
}, function (errRes) {

});
```

So, I am now thinking of refactoring the code as follow but I am not sure whether this could be done.

```
function getUserDetail2 (res) {

};

UserAPI.GetUserDetails1({ ID: id})
.then(getUserDetail2(res))
.catch(function (errRes) {
    // catch error if any error occur
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass reference of function instead of calling it there.

```
UserAPI.GetUserDetails1({ ID: id})
.then(getUserDetail2) //passed getUserDetail2 method here
.catch(function (errRes) {
    // catch error if any error occur
});
```

Comment: I see. thanks. Do you mind to tell if all errorResponse will actually be catch? What is the difference between function (errRes) vs catch(errRes)?? Do both return the same value?

Comment: @vincentsty I'd highly recommend you to go through [this article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/01/javascript-promises-and-error-handling.aspx)